# Creating subtype of a subtype with Table-per-Type (TPT) approach using ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using the table per type strategy with a class named `Assets` as my super-type and another class `PropertyAsset` inheriting it. However, there are two classes inheriting the `PropertyAsset` class, named `InternalProperty` & `ExternalProperty`.

Asset Table

```cs
public class Asset : Entity, IMustHaveCompany
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpectedLife { get; set; }
    public decimal EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    
    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual Company.Company? Company { get; set; }    

    #endregion
}
```

Property Asset Table

```
public class PropertyAsset : Asset
{
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
    public int Bathrooms { get; set; }
    public decimal LeaseRate { get; set; }
    public decimal SqFeet { get; set; }
}
```

External Property Table

```
public class ExternalProperty : PropertyAsset
{
    public decimal LeaseRatePerSquareFt { get; set; }
    public decimal SquareFoot { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualIncome { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthlyLease { get; set; }
}
```

Internal Property Table

```
public class InternalProperty : PropertyAsset
{
    public decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public decimal DownPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentsRemaining { get; set; }
    public decimal Borrowing { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualTax { get; set; }
}
```

How would I create let's say the `InternalProperty` entity using this approach, with the values reflecting upwards? My thoughts are that I would need to use a DTO and map it with AutoMapper, but when thinking about it, I doubt that approach will work, or if it would, I'd need to create three entities separately (`InternalProperty`, then PropertyAsset and somehow use the Id of the newly created internal property, and then finally the Asset table itself.)

Am I using the TPT approach incorrectly in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd need to create three entities separately (`InternalProperty`, then `PropertyAsset` and somehow use the Id of the newly created internal property, and then finally the `Asset` table itself.)

Negative. Inheritance represents *is a* relationship, so you just need to create a single object of the desired type, add it to the context and EF Core will do the rest.

this, along with polymorphic queries is the whole purpose of EF Core database inheritance strategies. The only difference between different strategies (TPH, TPT) is how the data is stored (single table with discriminator column and union of all base and directly or indirectly derived entities data vs multiple tables storing just the data associated with the corresponding level of the entity hierarchy), respectively how is queried. But in both cases, you simply add *assignable* object instance to the corresponding set. For instance, if you have

```cs
var instance = new InternalProperty { ... };
```

then you can use any of the following

```cs
context.Set<Asset>().Add(instance);
context.Set<PropertyAsset>().Add(instance);
context.Set<InternalProperty>().Add(instance);
context.Add(instance);
```

(the last accepts `object` type argument).

All that works because EF Core uses the actual type (basically `instance.GetType()` except for proxy types) for handling the operation.

Similar happens when querying. Polymorphic queries means that anytime you query a base level, it includes the level plus all direct and indirect derived levels, with correct actual instance types.

For instance, if you query `context.Set<Asset>`, you would get all `Asset`, `PropertyAsset`, `ExternalProperty` and `InternalProperty` instances (with correct actual type). `context.Set<PropertyAsset>` will include all `PropertyAsset`, `ExternalProperty` and `InternalProperty` entities while `context.Set<ExternalProperty>` and `context.Set<ExternalProperty>` will include only the corresponding items.

Shortly, it is combination of query filter and query materialization creating correct object type and populating it with data. All that done automatically by EF Core.

So the usage of TPT (or TPH) is pretty valid for such object model. Just mark the classes (if any) which are not supposed to be creatable as `abstract`. It won't change the database structure (especially for TPT), but will allow generating more efficient queries (filters and joins) by EF Core.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm still confused about how to create the entity, for instance if I wanted to create an `Asset`, could that be done at the top level, i.e. ```var asset = new Asset { etc ...}```, or would I need to create this as e.g. an `InternalProperty` and use a model to fill in the rest of the fields? I guess I am confused about how EF handles the creation of the relationship.

Comment: I think I get it now. I was having trouble with inheritance because there was no parameter-less constructor in any of the parent-classes, and therefore couldn't access the properties in the subclasses. But now I understand... `PropertyAsset` should be abstract because it should only be created by its child classes. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Jacob You don't create `Asset` instance, you create concrete class instance, let say `InternalProperty`. Then populate it with data (it has all `Asset` properties), then pass it to EF Core. It will populate the 3 tables with correct PK/FKs.

Comment: If you query the base type and the results include objects of many derived types, how would you load navigation properties of certain derived types? for example if you get a result set from Set<Asset>, will the items of type InternalProperty have its PaymentMethod loaded automatically?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Automatically - no. With eager loading - as explained in the [Include on derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#include-on-derived-types) docs.